# How do I generate a SQL script from my diagram in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've created an EER diagram with tables, foreign keys, etc in MySQL Workbench and now I want to generate a ".sql" script that will create this database. How do I do that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that can be found in the MySQL documentation (with some effort)

Comment: If that were a criterion to close a question on SO then we probably can do this for 50% or more questions (event tho this particular one was simple).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See File -> Export -> Forward Engineer SQL Create Script...